# How to use regExp to find value in cell and put in next row in spreadsheet?

Tags: javascript, regex, google-sheets

I have table with one row which contains text. I need to extract value from this text using regExp.

My code is:

```
function myfunc(){

  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var range = spreadsheet.getRange('A1:B1000');
  var regExp = /(\?<=Баланс)(.*)(\?=р8)/;

  for (var i = 1; i < 1000; i++) {
    var cell = range.getCell(i,1)
    var cell2 = range.getCell(i,2)    
    var val = regExp.exec(cell.getValue());
    cell2.setValue(val);
  }
}
```

But it doesn't do anything. What can be the problem?

Comment: The regex, use `/Баланс(.*?)р8/` and grab `val[1]`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to fix the patter:

```
/Баланс(.*?)р8/
```

Then, you may access the Group 1 value after matching with `regExp.exec(cell.getValue())`, it is accessible via `val[1]`.

```
function myfunc(){
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var range = spreadsheet.getRange('A1:B1000');
  var regExp = /Баланс(.*?)р8/;

  for (var i = 1; i < 1000; i++) {
    var cell = range.getCell(i,1)
    var cell2 = range.getCell(i,2)    
    var val = regExp.exec(cell.getValue());
    if (val) {
      cell2.setValue(val[1]);
    }
  }
}
```

Note that you may get what you need with a mere `=REGEXEXTRACT`:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(A13,"Баланс(.*?)р8")
```

[image]